# Mpeg-DASH playback issues in Edge browser with VideoJS

Tags: html5-video, video.js, wowza, mpeg-dash

I am creating a dash player using [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-dash/) and I have hosted it in my local IIS server with HTTP protocol and port 90.

I have 2 types of DASH content

1. Publicly hosted DASH content
   (https://s3.amazonaws.com/_bc_dml/example-content/sintel_dash/sintel_vod.mpd)
2. Locally hosted DASH content (local Wowza server-3.7.4 on
   Ubuntu-16.04)

I am able to successfully playback content#1 on Windows-10 Chrome/Firefox/IE11/Edge. But I am not able to play the content#2 on Windows-10 Edge browser (Version:41.16299.402.0) and the same is playable on Chrome/Firefox/IE11.

On Edge browser it keeps re-requesting the MPD file and the HTTP request will not leave the browser on browser developer tools you can see the content being fetched 'from cache'.

**Error message:** "The media playback was aborted because too many consecutive download errors occurred."

Attached screenshots for further details.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYuoE.jpg),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c7ji.jpg)

This is the player test page code snippet

```js
<video id=example-video width=600 height=300 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls> </video>

<script src="video-7.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="dash.all.debug-2.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="videojs-dash.min-2.10.0.js"></script>
<script>
  var player = videojs('example-video');
  player.src({ src: 'http://devstream.clearhub.tv/dashpoc/_definst_/smil:nmdcPH/20180604/others/25903.smil/manifest.mpd', type: 'application/dash+xml'});
  player.play();
</script>
```

getting error "The media playback was aborted because too many consecutive download errors occurred."

Comment: This is working in Edge browser version 40. It seems to be broken in 41 version of Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

If same code works on other browsers but you can only get unspecific error messages in that browser, you could test some alternatives to your code.

You can try using HTTPS as most browsers require matching secure content in latest versions. 
Also HLS can be used with Wowza SE.